# apt: how to search using package tags?

Tags: debian, apt, dpkg, deb

Some (most?) packages in Debian, have tags. For example:

```
=# apt-cache show squirrelmail | perl -lne 'print if /^Tag:/.../^\S/'
Tag: implemented-in::php, interface::web, mail::imap, mail::smtp,
 mail::user-agent, network::server, protocol::http, protocol::imap,
 protocol::smtp, role::program, scope::application, use::browsing,
 use::editing, use::searching, use::transmission, use::viewing,
 web::TODO, web::application, works-with::mail
Section: web
```

But, I can't find a way, to list all packages with given tag. Is it possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You probably want to take a look at [all the documentation surrounding Debtags](http://wiki.debian.org/Debtags).  It's... not as simple as you might think.  No, I don't know why, either.

Comment: Just a word of comment - I picked this answer, because `debtags` seems to do what I need (`debtags search "mail::user-agent && interface::web"`) while axi-cache seems to have problems when searching for multiple tags at once.

Comment: I have… had neither aptitude nor debtags installed… and I neither know why nor do I understand why and how apt(-cache) search doesn't/can't use tags.  Debian… sometimes it annoys me *very* much.  And has done so for over 20 years.

Answer (score 14):

I wonder why people haven't suggested:

```
aptitude search '?tag(protocol::dns)'
```

`aptitude search` allows complex search queries with probes on different package description fields and logical operators:

```
aptitude search '?tag(game::strategy) ?installed'
aptitude search '?tag(protocol::dns) !?installed'
```

Refer to *Search term reference* in *Aptitude User's Manual* from `aptitude-doc-en` package (`/usr/share/doc/aptitude/html/en/index.html`).

Comment: this does it very well

Comment: `aptitude search '?tag(section::games)' chess` seems to list all chess games on Ubuntu... the reason I gave this example is that `apt-cache show` lists the section of an Ubuntu package. The command you just stated here enables us to search using those sections (I guess...(?)) :)

Answer (score 6):

Use `axi-cache` from the `apt-xapian-index` package. You can, for example do `axi-cache search --all protocol::smtp`. The tab-completion for `axi-cache` is extremely advanced, so hit tab often. For example, `axi-cache search --all protocol::smtp <tab><tab>` will show you what other tags you might want based on the fact that you already specified the first.

Comment: axi-cache is nice as we can mix and match keywords and tags. For example 'axi-cache search scanner suite::kde' will search packages with 'scanner' word and have 'suite::kde' tag.

Answer (score 5):

If you install `debtags`, you can use it to search for tags like this:

```sh
debtags search made-of::icons
debtags search "made-of::icons && x11::theme"
debtags tagcat               # Shows all tags and their description
debtags tagshow x11::TODO    # Shows a single tag plus description
```

`debtags` also comes with a nice bash tab completion.